# SQL Time how to find last record but just return one

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

How would I go about doing this say I have a bunch of registers and they have a terminal id = 4741 and I only want the very last record of that day. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [id]
    ,[data_atualizacao]
    ,[direcao]   
    ,[velocidade]
    ,[latitude]
    ,[longitude]
    ,[nivel_bateria]
    ,[enum_status_gps]
    ,[id_terminal]
FROM 
    [TecnologiaGPS_V2].[dbo].[posicao_historico_terminal_82015]
WHERE
    id_terminal = 4741
ORDER BY 
    data_atualizacao ASC
```

But say that above query returns the following I only want however the last time the 19:57:58 one i thought order by would have been enough  but it just brings me them in ascending order.

```
 id_terminal 19:57:05
 id_terminal 19:57:15
 id_temminal 19:57:58
```

This is how I am getting my data back in c#

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM motorista where id = " + driverId +" order_by data_atualizacao", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Check is the reader has any rows at all before starting to read.
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // Read advances to the next row.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                motorista motorist = new motorista();
                // To avoid unexpected bugs access columns by name.
                motorist.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
                motorist.nome = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("nome"));
                motorist.numero_registro = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("numero_registro"));
                morotistList.Add(motorist);
            }

            return morotistList.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I get the very most recent time stamp and also is my code sufficient when I would be paging through a record set of six million entries. Even though I will always have the terminal id to pass to the query.

Comment: Very last record of what day?

Comment: sorry its the last record of the current day

Comment: If you are running throught this amount of records maybe you want to group by day. Do you have a column with the date of the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    [id], [data_atualizacao], [direcao], [velocidade], 
    [latitude], [longitude], [nivel_bateria], 
    [enum_status_gps],[id_terminal]
from 
    (select
         [id],
         row_number() over(partition by id order by data_atualizacao desc) rn,
         [data_atualizacao], [direcao], [velocidade],
         [latitude], [longitude], [nivel_bateria],
         [enum_status_gps], [id_terminal]
     from  
         [TecnologiaGPS_V2].[dbo].[posicao_historico_terminal_82015]
     where 
         id_terminal = 4741) t
where 
    t.rn = 1
```

You can use a `row_number` window function to get the latest record for each id.

Comment: sorry its the last record of the current day

Comment: will it have same `id` have records on other days as well? If so, this would still give you only the latest record.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 1 * 
from TecnologiaGPS_V2 
where id_terminal = 4741 
order by data_atualizacao desc
```

Comment: sorry its the last record of the current day

Comment: you can add in the where 

where id_terminal =4741 and somecolumnwith the date  = getdate()

Comment: By sorting by date descending, you will always have the most recent row of the current day at the top. There should be no need to compare the dates unless you need to select the most recent record from a previous day.

Comment: @Alex I just need select the top one as you rightly said so will try this

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sorting the data you could also use and aggregate as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    [TecnologiaGPS_V2].[dbo].[posicao_historico_terminal_82015]
WHERE
    id_terminal = 4741
AND data_atualizacao = (SELECT MAX (data_atualizacao) FROM [TecnologiaGPS_V2].[dbo].[posicao_historico_terminal_82015] as subquery 
WHERE id_terminal = subquery.id_terminal)
```

Doing an order by can cause extra work by the database server. Sorts can be extremely expensive based on the data set size. While you can also rely on an index to also keep it sorted for you, you are going to pay in index maintenance. Sql server is good at aggregations, this may perform better overall. Also, based on your table definition you are guaranteed 1 row.

Comment: The only way to knowing this for sure is looking at the execution plan, the index structure, the amount of data and if the statistics are updated.

Answer (score 0):

select top 1 * from tablename where [condition] order by [column] desc;

to check run the each query one by one.

SELECT  * FROM Orders where EmployeeID = 4 ;

SELECT top 1 * FROM Orders where EmployeeID = 4 order by OrderDate desc;

in

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_first&ss=-1